# How can I constrain a bone to follow another bone from the same armature?

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones

here's my question, simply and straight:

How can I make a bone follow (location and rotation) another bone from the same armature? Imagine a character with hand resting over the hip, I need to move the hip bone, and make the hand follow it.

What I already tried:

- Creating an empty, vertex parenting it in the hip's mesh, and from the hand bone create a CHILD OF constrain to the empty. Not working.
- Creating two empties, vertex parented one to he hip, and one to he hand, and adding rotation and location constrains (because copy transforms constrain doesn't have OFFSET) and struggling with the local space and the offset to pose the hand. This kind of works, but it looks to me that there must be a simpler way, the struggle with the OFFSET and the local/ world/ wherever space is insane.

Any thoughts how to make it in a simple way? I'm coming from Maya, and I'm used to constrain between rig controllers all the time (controllers in Maya are nurbs curves, not shaped bones), so there is no trouble with the hierarchy as it is with Blender bones.

Please, let me know if you need additional explanation.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think Child Of is what you're looking for, why didn't it work?

Comment: Yeah, that was my first guess, but if I select the hand bone, and add it a CHILD OF constrain, in the TARGET, Blender (2.80 beta), doesn't let me select the armature,  -I think because the hand and the hip bones are in the same armature, and it messes up the bone hierarchy.

Comment: so maybe you need to rethink the hierarchy, if your hand is parented to a bone (IK controller of the lowerarm), then give this bone the Child Of constraint

Comment: I can give this a try, I'll let you know!

Comment: Sorry, no luck. No matter wich bone do I add the CHILD OF constrain, Blender won't let me select the armature as target. The problem is still the same, it seems like Blender can't constrain a bone to another bone in the same armature, but I can't accept this! There must be a way for such a simple operation!

Comment: You can make a bone child of another bone within the same armature, but perhaps my explanation was not clear enough: typically for the arm you'll have the upper arm, lower arm, hand, and controller. The controller has no parent (except root bone), the hand is parented to the controller, the lower arm has an IK constraint with the controller as target. Now if you give the Child Of constraint to the controller, it works fine, the controller will follow the bone that you have chosen as target, and the hand and lower arm will follow

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I was trying to add the constraints in the **Object Constraints** tab, instead of **Bone Constraints**.
You can make a bone child to another bone in the same armature with a **Bone Constraints**!